# Не подключаются стили для popupMenu

Tags: android, android-style, popupmenu

Помогите решить проблему. Хочу создать popup-menu c темным фоном и белым цветом шрифта. Но пользовательский стиль не подключается почему-то к меню.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@null</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.darkPopupStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.darkPopupStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/popup_drawable</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

popup_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color
            android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Код, где создаю объект меню и подключаю к нему стили:

```
ContextWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme_darkPopupStyle);
                PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);
```

Использую `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu`

Помогите решить проблему. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme.darkPopupStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
```

замените на:

```
<style name="AppTheme.darkPopupStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
```